# Windows Server 2008 R2 having FIVE different IPs?

Tags: router, ip, windows-server-2008-r2

No idea what's going on. Windows Server 2008 R2 connected to a Buffalo DD-WRT router. I set a 192.168.1.150 static IP on the Windows and NOT on the router. Maybe 75% of the time it works fine, the rest of the time it would go haywire as in the screenshot. Sometimes it would have two, or THREE different IPs?? I have no idea what's going on. I've restarted the Buffalo a bunch of times, made sure all leases but the correct one have expired, etc. Please help! Thanks!

Edit: output of ipconfig /all

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : ericom
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter IFCA:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR8151 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 50-E5-49-18-94-B7
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7879:756c:a0ef:82c0%15(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.150(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.100(Deprecated) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.118(Deprecated) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.138(Deprecated) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.189(Deprecated) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 189850953
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-D1-DF-89-50-E5-49-18-94-B7
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{2E16DC4C-FB08-48BE-822D-121E3CC66A64}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6abd:863:961:3f57:fe69(Preferred) 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::863:961:3f57:fe69%11(Preferred) 
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Comment: nobody? Not even a comment? :(

Comment: What is this screenshot of ? It would also help to have the output of ipconfig.

Comment: I am no Windows expert. The line "DHCP Enabled no" means that the DHCP server on THIS MACHINE has been turned off, which implies someone else is assigning IP addresses. The presence of two more addresses is not in itself a cause for worry: you have not told us how many interfaces the pc has, (2 ethernet? 1 wifi?), plus there exist Virtual InterFaces (vifs), which appear as multiple interfaces on the same card. You should try to ascertain which process is in control of each socket, then we might be able to diagnose the problem, if there is one.

Comment: This is a screenshot of my LAN "Status". There is one ethernet and no wifi. Strange about the DHCP status. I will check that. But that is perhaps because I set the IP manually to a static value. I know nothing about virtual interfaces and have never set one up so I dont know why they are showing up. Please elaborate on that subject. Thanks

Comment: @rabbid Can you open CMD.exe as admin and write there "ipconfig /all" and show us the results? (Edit your question and put it there).

Comment: `ipconfig /all > file.txt` and add the contents of the file in your post.

Comment: And is the above photo taken off your router or from some application in Windows?

Comment: Does this server have any resources shared by virtual IP and/or DFS?

Comment: Hi all. I'm sorry for the late reply because I was out of town with limited connection to the server. I have edited the original post with output of ipconfig /all @Jet and harrymc.

Comment: @Colyn1337 how do check for resources shared by Virtual IP and/or DFS? Thank you!

Comment: Do you use PXE for booting?

Comment: The strange thing here is that the IP addresses are "deprecated". I thought this happened only for IPv6 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727003.aspx. Is this a lead? What happens if you disable IPv6?

Comment: In the GUI for the IP config you set IP=192.168.1.150, mask=255.255.255.0, Gateway=192.168.1.1 and DNS=192.168.1.1. What did you set the config to on the tab "alternative configuration"? Did you leave that as "auto assigned" or did you enter some IP address there?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae what is PXE?

Comment: @WernerHenze auto assigned

Comment: @rabbid Pre-Boot Execution Environment. It is used to boot pcs from a network configuration, no matter what your hard disk says.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae thanks for the explanation, and no, not using that. Honestly this is just a vanilla Windows Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `DHCP Enabled No` it shouldn't be getting any leases itself.

Virtual machines with bridged connections hosted on the server may get their own leases or show static addresses assigned to them.

Routing and Remote Access Service (RRAS) can be set to assign addresses from a DHCP server. So if your using the server to host VPN connections that could be what is getting the addresses. Do a `netsh ras show conf` to see if it's configured.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where do i set that setting?

Comment: Depends on what your using to run Virtual machines (Hyper V, VMWare etc). If you want the VMs to be accessible to other systems on the network then bridged is what you want to use. VMware FAQ: http://vmfaq.com/entry/34/

Comment: But im not running any virtual machines. Just a regular windows server

Comment: ipconfig /all will list all adapters along with the IP addresses they're assigned

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. I have edited the original post with the output of ipconfig /all

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that multiple IP addresses are specified on your server's Atheros network adapter.

Try this:

- Go to Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections
- Right click on the active Ethernet (Atheros) connection and select `Properties`
- Double click on `Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)`
- Click `Advanced`
- Make sure that `IP addresses` list contains only `192.168.1.150`

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. I have checked as you requested and indeed there is only one IP that is 192.168.1.150 listed. Default Gateway is set at 192.168.1.1. Thanks!

Comment: If you're not utilizing IPv6, try disabling it in connection properties and see if the deprecated addresses go away.